# using threepenny-gui/reactive in client/server programming

Tags: haskell, threepenny-gui

I am trying to figure out how to use Haskell [threepenny-gui](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/threepenny-gui) with its [reactive](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/threepenny-gui-0.4.2.0/docs/Reactive-Threepenny.html) functionality to write a program that lets

- the user select an item from a listBox
- send the selection to an external server
- get back a list of results from the server
- populate the listBox with the results
- repeat

It seems I will need to use `Handler`, `newEvent` and `register` to  do the above.  If someone could point me to some existing code that does something like the above that would be great.

The closest I have found is `GameThing.hs` in the threepenny-gui `samples` directory (but it doesn't use `register`).

UPDATE:

I am asking whether I should be using `Handler`, `newEvent` and `register` --- and, if so, some clarification or example of those functions.

Also, to be clear, the big picture is:

```
browser  --> threepenny-gui (on localhost) --> backend server (anywhere on network)
         <--                               <--
```

In other words, I need to do some IO (based on user selection) then display the results of that IO.

UPDATE:  here is my solution (based on @Taldykin's response): https://github.com/haroldcarr/rdf-triple-browser/tree/master/haskell/src

Comment: Have you tried? It's kind of futile to ask stack overflow to design an application for you; why don't you try breaking the problem into smaller parts and implementing them before asking for us to handle the big picture? We'd be happy to help with more pointed questions, but this is too broad.

Comment: I have tried and I am not asking for an application design.  See my update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

Here is a piece of code. I will add description a bit later.

```
{-# LANGUAGE LambdaCase #-}
import Graphics.UI.Threepenny as UI


main :: IO ()
main = do
  (evFillList, doFillList) <- newEvent
  initialList <- valuesSupply ""
  behFillList <- stepper initialList evFillList

  startGUI defaultConfig $ \win -> do
    list <- ul
    sel <- listBox
        behFillList
        (pure Nothing)
        (pure $ \it -> UI.span # set text it)

    getBody win #+ [grid [[element list, element sel]]]
    setFocus $ getElement sel

    on selectionChange (getElement sel) $ \case
      Nothing -> return ()
      Just ix -> do
        items <- currentValue behFillList
        let it = items !! ix
        liftIO $ valuesSupply it >>= doFillList
        element list #+ [li # set html it]
        setFocus $ getElement sel


valuesSupply :: String -> IO [String]
valuesSupply x = return [x ++ show i | i <- [0..9]]
```

Comment: I finally got around to writing a small blog entry on this.  Thanks for your help.  http://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/2v10rb/how_to_connect_threepennygui_to_external_events/