# How to build Infinite-scroll listbox using threepenny-gui

Tags: user-interface, haskell, infinite-scroll, slickgrid, threepenny-gui

Hello Haskell and Threepenny-GUI community,

I want to display a [ListBox](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/threepenny-gui-0.4.0.1/docs/Graphics-UI-Threepenny-Widgets.html#t:ListBox) which has infinite scrolling support. I have a table in an SQLite database with 100k - 1000k rows. I want to display rows in a ListBox. I got help from this post [threepenny-gui-reactive-in-client-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24784883/using-threepenny-gui-reactive-in-client-server-programming). I got the GUI working with two ListBoxes, one for the page number and the other for actual rows for that page.

Though my goal is to create a GUI that has just one display, something like a basic version but similar to this example using SlickGrid: http://mleibman.github.io/SlickGrid/examples/example4-model.html.

Comment: Threepenny-GUI (version 0.6) currently does not have an infinite scrolling widget built-in. Essentially, you have implement your own. Judging from the example that you have linked to, the key is that div elements are created and destroyed whenever the table is being scrolled, so that only the currently visible entries are present in the DOM tree.

Comment: @ErikAllik Thanks for the edits. I don't have a working code towards infinite scrolling. The code I got so far has two ListBoxes one for page numbers and another displays data rows. I plan to post the code on github.

Comment: @HeinrichApfelmus Could you please guide any example/skelton code? I wanted to understand what kind of events I could use? Will ListBox wouldn't be a good choice here? I think, I should confess that I am new to Haskell :)

Comment: @user5126372 I currently don't have any example code for infinite scrolling, sorry. What I'm saying is that it's more complicated to implement and definitely not supported by the simple-minded `ListBox` thing.